# Problem connecting Android app to automation devices using socket connection

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, io

This requirement for automation devices.

Hello, I want Send - Receive data using Static IPAddress and Port with WiFi connection. (**It's working fine for me using TCPIP Socket Programming.**)

Now, My phone connects with router wifi, but here Internet connection not available. Then after I want to do the above process between mobile devices and automation devices.

Is there any possible way to connect mobile devices and automation devices using only wifi connection (Wifi Internet connection not necessary in this case.)

Comment: If the automation devices generates a hotspot or access point then yes.

Comment: The automation device has Static IPAddress and Port Number. Right now I'm connecting with the automation device using Socket and TcpClient and it's working fine if Internet connection is available.

Comment: It is unclear for me if the automation device acts as a client or a server. Further its unclear where you use Socket and TcpClient. On Android or on the automation device. And in which sense that static ip is used? Where is the automation device connecting to? In short: pretty unclear what you are doing.